# Google drive get files with API-KEY

Tags: google-drive-api

I use below url for get files

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?name=xxx&key=yyy
```

But I get this error:

```
{
 "error": {
  "errors": [
   {
    "domain": "global",
    "reason": "forbidden",
    "message": "Insufficient permissions for this file",
    "locationType": "other",
    "location": "file.permissions"
   }
  ],
  "code": 403,
  "message": "Insufficient permissions for this file"
 }
}
```

I want get lists only with `key`

How I can?

Comment: Please see https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/list for more info/details on how to get the list of files using Drive API V2. Let me know if you have more questions.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe your goal as follows.

- You want to retrieve the file list of Google Drive using your API key.
- You want to achieve this using Drive API v2.

#### Issue and workaround:

The API key can be used for the public contents. So, unfortunately, you cannot all files on your Google Drive from the root folder using the API key. Because the root folder of Google Drive cannot be publicly shared. I thought that your error message might be due to this. (I'm not sure what you want to do using `name=xxx`. But, `https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?key=yyy` is trying to retrieve the file list of all files of Google Drive. In this case, such error occurs.) But, fortunately, when a folder in your Google Drive is publicly shared, the file list can be retrieved using the API key.

In this answer, I would like to introduce the method for retrieving the file list from the publicly shared folder in the Google Drive.

#### Sample endpoint:

When you test the following endpoint, please publicly share a folder in your Google Drive and use the folder ID of the folder. By this, the file list of the folder can be retrieved using the API key.

```
https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v2/files?q=%27folderId%27%20in%20parents&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]
```

- In this endpoint, `'folderId' in parents` is used as the search query. So, in this case, the folder of `folderId` is required to be publicly shared. When you use this script, please replace `folderId` to the folder ID of your folder which is publicly shared.
- When Drive API v3 is used, you can use the following endpoint.

  ```
    https://www.googleapis.com/drive/v3/files?q=%27folderId%27%20in%20parents&key=[YOUR_API_KEY]
  ```

#### Note:

- When you want to retrieve the file list including the subfolders with the folder structures, it is required to traverse the folders. In this case, I think that it is required to use the script.
- This answer supposes that your API key can be used Drive API. Please be careful this.

#### References:

- [Files: list of Drive API v2](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v2/reference/files/list)
- [Files: list of Drive API v3](https://developers.google.com/drive/api/v3/reference/files/list)

Comment: thank you. if i want get `my-drive`, can i set `my-drive` public? and `'my-drive' in parents` work correct?

Comment: @Parsa Nikoo Thank you for replying. Unfortunately, I'm not sure whether I could correctly understand about `my-drive` you are thinking. If you want to publicly share the root folder (your whole drive) of your Google Drive, unfortunately, it cannot be achieved. It seems that this is the current specification at Google side. If you create new folder in your Google Drive and you want to publicly share it, you can achieve this.

Comment: @Parsa Nikoo For example, if you want to publicly share all files and folders, how about creating new folder and move all files and folders to the created folder, and publicly share the top folder? By this, you can access them using the API key. But in that case, please be careful this. At that time, at first, I would like to recommend to test using a sample files.